# How to use orderBy using laravel relationship?

Tags: laravel-8

Let’s say we have a Post model and a Comment model. The Comment model has a `belongsTo()` relationship with the Post, while the Post has a `hasMany()` relationship with the comment. I am using the code `Post::orderBy('comments_count')->get();`
but not working.

Comment: Can any any one help to figure this out ?

Comment: in which order you want get the data ?

Comment: The posts which contains maximum comments will come to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the model you would have:

```
public function scopecountDescending($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('comments_count','DESC');
  }
```

And in your controller:

```
 $posts = Post::countDescending()->get();
```

or simply in your controller:

```
Post::orderBy('comments_count' , 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: I have used Post::orderBy('comments_count' , 'DESC')->get(); but not working.

Comment: you sure what's the result?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. $posts = Post::withCount('comments')
    ->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')
    ->get(); works fines for me.

Comment: ohh i thought  'comments_count'  is one of your column in table.